# Explaination concerning the polygonal generalized Schoenflies problem

Tags: geometric-topology, polygons

I'm having trouble understanding the status of the generalized polygonal Schoenflies problem : The french and the english version in wikipedia seem (at least to me) to state different things, as there might be problems with dimensions $d\le 5$. Moreover, all relevant litterature seem to date from the 1960s.

Here is the english wikipedia page.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem#Generalizations

My question is the following : Let us assume there is a piecewise affine injective map from $S^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Can it be extended to a injective piecewise affine map from the ball to what should be called the 'interior' of the polygon ?

Thanks

Comment: From $S^n$ to $R^{n+1}$, not to $R^n$! Also, the map of $B^{n+1}$ should be injective. This is a major open problem in the case $n=3$. The answer is nobody knows.

Comment: Thanks that confirms what the English Wikipedia says. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remaining (major) open problem (as far as Schoenflies is concerned) is the following:

Problem. Let $f: S^3\to R^4$ be a PL  embedding. Does $f$ extend to a PL embedding $B^4\to R^4$?

Since in dimensions $\le 6$ PL and DIFF categories are equivalent, you can replace "PL" with "smooth" in this problem. As for which way it will go, it's anybody's guess.

See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831918/about-generalized-schoenflies-problem-in-the-smooth-category?rq=1) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172884/several-questions-concerning-alexanders-theorem?rq=1).

Edit. (Per PVAL's comments): While what I said about dimension 4 is correct, in higher dimensions one has to be more careful in stating the known result ("Alexander-Schoenflies" Theorem in higher dimensions). The precise formulation of that theorem is the following (where $k\ne 3$):

Theorem A (PL category). Let $f: S^k \to E^{k+1}$ be a **locally flat** PL embedding. Then $f$ is PL isotopic to an embedding whose image is the standard round sphere.

Theorem B (Smooth category). Let $f: S^k \to E^{k+1}$ be a smooth embedding. Then $f$ is smoothly isotopic to a diffeomorphism to the standard round sphere in $E^{k+1}$.

Comment: If there does exist a counterexample in dimension 4, then $S^4=B_1 \cup B_2$ where $B_i$ are exotic $B^4$. My understanding is that we could possibly (there might be a proof that such a thing exists given 4D Schoenflies is false but I don't know it) have a PL map $S^4\to B^5$ where the link of a vertex of a point is $B_i$ and we do not know how to rule this out. My understanding is that a similar thing can happen in higher dimensions. In other words, if Schoenflies in dim 4 is false it is plausible that there exists non locally flat PL embeddings in dim >4.

Comment: @Moishe Cohen : I asked a follow-up question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2677526/does-nodes-of-a-polygon-and-cell-relationships-determine-the-shape-of-the-polygo ? If you would be se kind as to have a look, I would be very thankful.

Comment: @PVAL-inactive: You are right, in higher dimensions one needs to be more careful when stating the result. Incidentally, did you ever consider removing "inactive" from your user name?

Comment: @MoisheCohen For now my profile/name is representative of the person I want to be, rather than the person I am (not sure if I am joking or serious).